# From C# to Java

Tags: c#, java

I don't know whether this is a valid question to ask here or not, but I made an attempt.

I am basically a C# guy. But since the last 7 days I have been asked to work in java (J2SE 1.4)  and I am working in that. and gradually I am finding interest in that.

I want to learn more about it and since I am finding a lot of similarity between C# and Java(what ever I have gleaned + worked so far in those 7 days), I am planning to steer my career in that.

But having spent for more than 2 years in C# and then moving to java, will it be a problem in future (say after 3/4 months) if I need to change my job.. I mean my most of the exp. lies in C# and just started JAVA. so how the technical panel will accept me if I need to change the platform?

Thanks

Comment: Don't go to the Dark Side of the force young Newbie! C# is just the opposite of java! If I were in your shoes, I would have quit (first I would tell the boss that I can make one exception, but the next I'm leaving). Good luck with whatever decision you make. I'm also not sure, but I guess this topic should be on Meta stackoverflow

Comment: @BrunoLM, Nope, here is the correct spot as the Q isn't talking about SO at all, thus being on meta would be the wrong place.

Comment: @BrunoLM: Altough not identical, you'd have a very hard time finding two mainstream languages that are as close as Java and C#... Saying they're *"just the opposite"* [sic] is more than a bit strong. C# is basically a Java that only works on a proprietary OS thanks to vendor lock-in (Mono didn't turn out that well did it ;). Pick your poison.  OS X? Un*X? servers? ever heard of servers? :)

Comment: @BrunoLM, "Dark side of the force"? Isn't C# and its platform more proprietary than Java? C# and Java are not opposite (whatever that means), C# might even be Microsoft's answer to Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Focus on becoming a better developer.  Learn as many languages as you can.  Any employer that won't hire you because you don't have X months experience with Java/C#/MSMQ/LOLCODE is clueless.

Good companies want to hire smart, well-rounded developers.  Not someone who listed a magic combination of technologies on their CV.

Comment: Yes, but there are a lot of bad companies out there :)

Comment: I would recommend you to do what you like, and not to `learn` all languages, IMO that's a really bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

I think most everybody on this site would encourage you to learn a new language if it interests you. IMHO, the fact that you've been focusing on C# would not stop me from hiring you in a Java position. If you have a strong grasp of C# then you should not have any problem switching to Java.

Answer (score 1):

> so how the technical panel will accept me if I need to change the platform?

If they have any sense, they will look at the amount of Java experience you have, and also take into account that you have significant experience in a technically similar language.

People in the IT industry are constantly learning new (or different) technologies.  Any recruiter who will only look at someone's experience in the primary language / technologies / buzzwords for the current job is going to miss a lot of good talent with broader knowledge and experience.